# Control M schedule change

Tags: control-m

I have a question for control M schedule change.
For exmaple: I have three jobs,in my current plan, A,B and C which run in control M daily in sequence with dependency as A->B->C  .

I don't want to run job B on Monday so C would start after A on Monday and A> B >C on other days.
Is it possible to achieve this without having to create two plans (one which run on Monday for A>C
and A>B >C for other days) ?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

```
        ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Control-M are you using? If you are using v21 (or above) then the concept of "bridging conditions" has been added nd this would be the best solution for you.

If you're on v20 or lower, let me know.